How can I host the HTML file on Colab?
When running a Python backend.py. There is an HTML file that acts as a website to show the results; Colab is not hosted locally, and only one task can be executed at a time on Colab (I think). Is there any way to host a web from Colab that is an HTML file?
I tried the ways to host the HTML, but as only one task can run, I can’t have a constant web that updates when viewing the web, and vise versa.

Use Gradio or Streamlit
Gradio and Streamlit are Python libraries designed for creating web apps directly in Colab. They are simpler and more robust if you don’t need to control the exact HTML.

Install Gradio:

    !pip install gradio


Create a Gradio app:
Gradio allows you to build interfaces easily and they can update dynamically.

import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"

interface = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text")
interface.launch(share=True)


Run and share:

This code will create a simple web app where you can input your name and receive a greeting. The share=True flag generates a public link to the web app.

You can use flask but gradio is way more simpler.
